# PyQt4 : can't change the color of my (html) message text

Tags: python-3.x, colors, pyqt4

For a Python3/PyQt4 project, I'm using a SplashScreen window with some text displayed on it, splitted into several lines :

```
self.showMessage("line1<br/>line2",
                 QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop,
                 QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
```

Everything's fine if the text has no HTML markup : my text is printed in red. But if I use < br/> (or some other HTML symbols) my text is only printed in black (the default value). I can't see nothing in the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplashscreen.html#details) that could help me.

Any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it : since I write HTML strings, the colors must be defined in the HTML string :

```
msg = "<span style=\"color:#FF0000\">string in red</span>"
self.showMessage(msg)
```